# Anaconda install freeze after download

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When switching to different Python version, conda downloaded all packages but freeze after that in the same place:
[image]

I've reinstalled Anaconda many times, nothing helped.

The same occurs with both commands:

`conda install python=3.4.5`

`conda create -n py34 python=3.4.5 anaconda`

EDIT:

- Windows 7
- Anaconda 4.3.1 x86_64
- ~30GB free

I would be very glad for your help!

Comment: Please include more details in question like `operating system`, `version`. Also check if there is enough memory available.

Comment: OK, i figured it out - you should just wait ;)

Comment: Please post the solution that you found. I came here looking for an answer to your same problem.